# imagick PNG encodeing problems

Tags: php, imagick

Ok I have this code

```
<?php

/* Create the object */
$image = new Imagick('http://mysite.org.uk/login/tiftest/1.tif');
$count = $image->getNumberImages();

##echo "<h3 style=\"font: bold 12pt Arial\">Total Number of Images Extracted ".
##  "from the TIF : ".$image->getNumberImages()."</h3>";
 $x =0;

foreach ( $image as $image ) {  
    $x++;
    $image->setImageFormat( 'png' );
    $image->thumbnailImage(150, 120);

    echo "<img id='" . $x . "' src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($image)."' />";


}
?>
```

This does work and the images display properly but I have had to encode the image with base64_encode and the image as :

```
<img id="1" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAC0CAQAAAD1RyCWAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8A==">
```

How can I get roun this so it just displays as

```
<img id='1' src=' ** something normal like image file name **'  />
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

What about using writeImage()?

Like:

$image->writeImage('preview/' . $x . '.png');

then use it in html:

```
echo "<img id ...  src="preview/" . $x . ".png">
```

Comment: Thanks ratti but I cant write the file to a folder this is all to be done on the fly